# Using adjustbox withouth changing fontsize

Tags: tables, fontsize, width, adjustbox

I am trying to adjust the table to the \textwidth but it changes the size of the font and becomes too big. Is there any way to fix the width of the table to the margins (1\textwidth) without changing automatically the fontsize? Using \tiny seems not to work. Thank you very much any help is appreciate it

\begin{table}[!htb]

```
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}    
    \tiny           
    \begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}            
        \hline
        \cellcolor{azultabla}{\textbf{\tiny{Range}}}& 
        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{azultabla}{\textbf{\tiny{Return }}}}                                                                 
        \\ 
        \hline
        & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\tiny{Spec.}}& 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\tiny{Meas.}}& 
        \tiny{Pass / Fail}        
        \\ 
        \hline
        \tiny{RF}& 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\tiny{\textgreater 10}}& 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\tiny{xxxx}}& 
        \tiny{xxxx}                    
        \\ 
        \hline
        \tiny{IF}& 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\tiny{\textgreater 10.9}}& 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\tiny{xxxx}}& 
        \tiny{xxxx}                    
        \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
```

\end{table}

Comment: Not quite understood. Are you trying to create a table that is as wide as the text, but the current one is too small and thus adjustbox scales it up?

Comment: never use adjustbox or resizebox on tables it forces inconsistent fonts as you show

Comment: It is hard to understand your code as you did not provide a full minimal example so others cannot just copy and test your code.

Comment: \tiny does not take an argument use \tiny abc  not \tiny{ABC}

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I want to fix the size of a table to the margins (2cm left and 2cm right). If i use {adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}, then okay, it is fixed to the margins but the fontsize of the content of the table grows a lot. I want to fix this size without changing the size of the content of my table.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the `tabularx` package instead

Comment: Will have a look. I appreciate it

Comment: See also tabular* (adjusts spaces between columns).  Standard LaTeX.

Comment: As said, do not resize the table, use `tabular*`, `talbularx` or `tabulary` to fit it to `\linewidth` (always safer than to `\textwidth`)  and then reduce the font if needed. Also consider a `\centering` before a simple  tabular without insisting on stretching the table to the margins, it could look even better.

Answer (score 1):

Never scale tables it just produces inconsistent font sizes. If you do want small text the syntax is `\tiny xxx` not `\tiny{xxx}` it does not take an argument.

You can specify a full width table in various ways, I use `tabularx` here, although the unstretched table is easier to read. I also removed the `\multicolumn{1}` as they were not doing anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tables]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\definecolor{azultabla}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]

\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}            
        \hline
        \cellcolor{azultabla}{\textbf{Range}}& 
        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{azultabla}{\textbf{Return}}}                                                                 
        \\ 
        \hline
        & 
        Spec.& 
        Meas.& 
        Pass / Fail       
        \\ 
        \hline
        RF& 
        \textgreater 10& 
        xxxx& 
        xxxx                   
        \\ 
        \hline
        IF& 
        \textgreater 10.9& 
        xxxx& 
        xxxx                   
        \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\bigskip
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|C|C|C|C|@{}}            
        \hline
        \cellcolor{azultabla}{\textbf{Range}}& 
        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{azultabla}{\textbf{Return}}}                                                                 
        \\ 
        \hline
        & 
        Spec.& 
        Meas.& 
        Pass / Fail       
        \\ 
        \hline
        RF& 
        \textgreater 10& 
        xxxx& 
        xxxx                   
        \\ 
        \hline
        IF& 
        \textgreater 10.9& 
        xxxx& 
        xxxx                   
        \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```