# Highlight a specific row using csvsimple marco

Tags: macros, csvsimple

I want to highlight a specific row using the row number in `csvsimple-l3` but I don't know how.
For example, I need to bold the 4th row but I don't want to add

```
row{4} = {font=\bfseries}
```

to `mycsvstyle` because I will use this style for other tables.
How can I define a macro to set the style for a row that I want using the row number?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{filecontents*}{report.csv}
"PRODUCT_CODE","PRODUCT_NAME","LIST_PRICE","DISCOUNT_PERCENT"
"sg","Gibson SG","2517","52"
"fg700s","Yamaha FG700S","489.99","39"
"rodriguez","Rodriguez Caballero 11","415","38"
"strat","Fender Stratocaster","699","30"
"les_paul","Gibson Les Paul","1299","30"
"ludwig","Ludwig 5-piece Drum Set with Cymbals","699.99","30"
"precision","Fender Precision","799.99","30"
"hofner","Hofner Icon","499.99","25"
"tama","Tama 5-Piece Drum Set with Cymbals","799.99","15"
"washburn","Washburn D10S","299","0"
\end{filecontents*}

\definecolor{codebgtable}{HTML}{F2F2F2}

\csvstyle{mycsvstyle}{
    respect underscore,
    before reading={\catcode`\"=9},
    after reading={\catcode`\"=13},
    no head,
    tabularray = {
    rowsep=5pt,colsep=9pt,
    stretch=1.3,
    %hlines,
    vlines,
    row{odd} = {codebgtable},
    row{1} = {codebgtable, font=\bfseries, halign = c},
    },
    table head = {\hline},
    table foot = {\hline},
    late after first line = {\\\hline},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{1.\textwidth}{!}{
        \csvreader[mycsvstyle]{report.csv}{
        %if \thecsvrow = 4 \setrow{\bfseries}
        }{
        \csvlinetotablerow
        }
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a track: row{#1}={font=\bfseries} and \csvreader[mycsvstyle=4]{report.csv}{... But to improve. Doesn't work without arguments.

Comment: work with \csvreader[mycsvstyle=0]{report.csv}{ but not very nice

Comment: Unrelated, \resizebox doesn't seem like a good idea. see this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666900/using-adjustbox-withouth -changing-fontsize/674267#674267